# Apache HttpClient POST does not work with entity

Tags: java, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I developed a simple Java socket-based web server which can read the request from a client. For the client I use the Apache HttpClient library with the following code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:7777/");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null)
{
  System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
}
```

When I execute the code, the server gets this request from the client:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1 
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:7777 
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

This is ok. But now I want to send some data via HTTP-POST so I extended my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:7777/");
// Extension:
StringEntity testString = new StringEntity("Hello World!", "text/plain", "UTF-8");
httppost.addHeader(testString.getContentType());
httppost.setEntity(testString);
//
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null)
{
  System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
}
```

If I execute the code now, nothing goes to the server. If I remove "httppost.setEntity(testString);" everything will work like described in the beginning. So the problem must be at "httppost.setEntity(testString);".

Does anyone know why nothing is sent when I use "setEntity"? Is there another way to transfer the data? I already tried this example: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java but without success.

Perhaps the problem lies on my webserver. How should a response for a successful request look like? 
I use this message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: RAKETE Web server/0.1 (Java)
Content-Length: 2
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Hey were you able to solve this?